# Amazon EC2 Windows AMI booting slowly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I've inherited a system that has an custom AMI based on Windows Server 2019.  This AMI boots up in about 60-90 seconds.  Its based on Full Windows Server 2019 - not the stripped down Core version. The person who made it isn't around any more.

I'm trying to make a new version of this AMI, but despite trying for days I get 3 minute boot times on my own version.  I tried to build what I need in Server 2019 Core, but still my boot time is about 2 minutes.

I've tried running EC2 Launch with various options but I can't figure out what's so special about this AMI that makes it boot so fast.

What might I be doing wrong in making my own AMI, and what thing can I try to make my own version boot faster?

Comment: I assume that the EBS volume settings are same, note like the old AMI works on fast `io1` volume, and you are using basic `gp2`?

Comment: They're using the same disk types